# How to get Date in java.util.Date instead of Unix Timestamp in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, milliseconds, java.util.date

I have an .sh script on my Linux server.

I need the date in milliseconds in Java, but everything I find on the net is giving me Unix Timestamp.

Like this: `date=$(date -d 'today 00:00:00' "+%s")`

I need java milliseconds, like here: https://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm.

How do I get that easily without writing a long java code?
There has to be an easy solution.

Comment: Multiply by 1000.

Comment: The use of `java.util.Date` as well as the use of milliseconds in Java are outmoded a long time ago. Also while your link *mentions* `java.util.Date`, I see no real sign of any `Date` object on the page. In Java a moment in time is represented by an `Instant` which internally stores seconds and nanoseconds. [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Sorry that I didn’t set the intention right: my comment was rather meant as helpful for other readers than for yourself. Though I should of course be pleased if you could use or for your next project or the one after that. I also have to deal with `Date` and other old types when maintaining old software sometimes.

Comment: As to your comments to my person and my experience, you have guessed wrongly, and I find it inappropriate to embark on such a discussion on Stack Overflow at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just unix epoch in milliseconds instead of seconds, so simply replace `+%s` with `+%s%3N`.

```bash
epoch_milli=$( date -d 'today 00:00:00' +%s%3N )
```

```
$ date +%s; date +%s%3N
1666798614
1666798614357
```

[Conversion using your site](https://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm?millis=1666798614357&m2d=Convert)

Comment: Thank you! It worked!
To be honest, I never understood the difference. Now I do :-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `date` supports this format

```
%N     nanoseconds (000000000..999999999)
```

so you can do something like

```
date +%s.%N
```

to get nanoseconds, then you can do the math if you want millies.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I still marked the first answer as the right answer, because it was the first :-)